# What are p and p0 in ICC.Sample.Size

Tags: r, sample-size, intraclass-correlation

The purpose of this R package should be self-explanatory. However, its parameters are not. The [help page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ICC.Sample.Size/ICC.Sample.Size.pdf)  never explains what is meant by `p` and `p0`. It simply states:

> Calculates a sample size for given values of p, the null hypothesis
>   p0,number of raters (k), desired power and alpha.  Can also generate
>   sample sizes for different valuesof p, p0 or combinations of p and p0
>   from 0-1.

Are they supposed to be $\rho$ and $\rho_0$ (rho and rho-zero)?

Comment: Be careful with "never": clear explanations of these parameters appear throughout the help, such as the description of `p` as "The intraclass correlation coefficient obtained in the study."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `p` and `p0` do represent $\rho$ and $\rho_0$ from [(Zou 2012](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.5466)). The values presented in Table II match those computed by `calculateIccSampleSize()`.